# how long does it take for android to transition into doze mode?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

In android version 6.0+ 
assuming user has left the android somewhere, unplugged, power button pressed to lock it etc..

How much time does android spend in each state such as inactive, idle pending etc before it finally gets into idle ?

Now once in idle mode how long does it take to get into idle_maintenance mode and for how long does it stay there in idle_maintenance mode ?

Are these values constant or configurable or dependent on android version/manufacturer..

Please advise this is important for me to make important decisions about how to adjust my app for android ver 6.0/api 23+

Comment: Same question. Because there is very difficult task to test exactly how our application will behave in doze mode and how to handle that situation.

Answer (score 12):

You should not concern yourself with *when* the device enters doze mode, rather with *how does my app behave when the phone is in doze mode*. To test this, you simply need to force your phone into doze and observe your app's behavior:

```
$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
Revision eac51f2bb6a8-android
$ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle | grep mState
  mState=ACTIVE
$ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle
Now forced in to idle mode
$ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle | grep mState
  mState=IDLE
```

Even better, you should test your application under all the various pre-doze states:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step
Stepped to: ACTIVE
$ adb shell dumpsys battery unplug # emulate unplugging the charging cable
$ for i in {1..5}; do adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step; done
Stepped to: IDLE_PENDING
Stepped to: SENSING
Stepped to: LOCATING
Stepped to: IDLE
Stepped to: IDLE_MAINTENANCE
# repeats IDLE and IDLE_MAINTENANCE forever
$ adb shell dumpsys battery reset
$ adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step
Stepped to: ACTIVE
```

You should test your app in all of the above states to ensure proper operation. See also the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#testing_doze_and_app_standby).

---

Now, if you insist on knowing the parameters of doze and maintenance, you should consult the full output of `adb shell dumpsys deviceidle`. When the device is `IDLE`, near the end of the output you will see:

```
mNextAlarmTime=+59m35s863ms
```

which derives from:

```
idle_to=+60m0s0ms
```

Also, unless the phone is woken up by the user, the next idle timeout is going to be larger, influenced by this parameter:

```
mNextIdleDelay=+2h0m0s0ms
```

etc. I am unaware of any official documentation about this, so take my interpretation with a grain of salt.

Comment: If you are observing the state on win10, you should use ```.\adb.exe shell dumpsys deviceidle | Select-String -Pattern mState*``` (powershell) instead of linux command.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with wanting to know when doze mode kicks in. This knowledge can be useful for narrowing down an issue with a problematic background service.

Comment: Upvoted for info on how to force the device into different states.. thanks!